# x = Concatenate(axis=1)([out1, out2, out3, out4]) ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis

Tags: python, keras

I found this code on the internet and trying to expand it adding the EfficientNetB3, but I am getting this error. I don't understand this technique, does it has a name?

```py
#define vgg + resnet50 + densenet
model1 = create_base_model(vgg16.VGG16, (224, 224), vgg16.preprocess_input)
model2 = create_base_model(resnet50.ResNet50, (224, 224), resnet50.preprocess_input)
model3 = create_base_model(inception_v3.InceptionV3, (299, 299), inception_v3.preprocess_input)

model4 = EfficientNetB3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(300, 300, 3))
# model5 = EfficientNetB5(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(456, 456, 3))

model1.trainable = False
model2.trainable = False
model3.trainable = False
model4.trainable = False
# model5.trainable = False

inpA = Input(shape = (224, 224, 3))
inpB = Input(shape = (299, 299, 3))
inpC = Input(shape = (300, 300, 3))
# inpD = Input(shape = (456, 456, 3))

out1 = model1(inpA)
out2 = model2(inpA)
out3 = model3(inpB)
out4 = model4(inpC)
# out5 = model5(inpD)

x = Concatenate(axis=1)([out1, out2, out3, out4])                
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes
 except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 512), 
(None, 2048), (None, 2048), (None, 10, 10, 1536)]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Concatenate need input to be the same shape, I think the only way is do a `GlobalAveragePooling2D` for every model. Though, just put `pooling='avg'` should enough.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the tip, it works, I have it like this now.

Comment: Hi @NatthaphonHongcharoen, thanks for the tip, it works!!!, I have it like this now.

Now it has another problem when I call fit.

history = multiple_pretained_model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    epochs = epochs,
    steps_per_epoch = train_num // batch_size,
    validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = validation_num // batch_size,
    verbose = 1,
    callbacks = [mc, es]
)

ValueError: Error. Expected to see 3 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays:

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen I was wondering why we get better results with this type of architecture than normal vanilla ones, is this the same as model ensembling?

Comment: The new problem is about input data, you dont put enough data because a new model.

Comment: No I don't think it will better, otherwise google would just publish this instead of single EfficientNet right?

Comment: Thanks! yes I need to add three sources of images the fit method, now I understand,  I wonder how I do that... :(

Comment: Depending on weather you use `fit` or `fit_generator`, if the former then you have to do change the `x` and `y`, if the latter then you need to edit your `data_generator`, probably it's `__getitem__` method.

Comment: If it's not a confidential, share your whole project might be easier for me to tell what to edit though.